# Message with a large List of simple objects

Tags: serialization, akka, akka.net

I am considering the pros and cons of how to work correctly with Akka.Net.
I added the Akka tag, because probably the underlying OS doesn't matter.

Suppose I have a list of 10.000 à 100.000 objects of relatively simple type.
Each object has a string, 2 integers and 10 doubles.
My estimate is that each object is 100 bytes.

So the complete list would be approx. 1 à 10 MB.

I would prefer to sent the list in 1 message, but I am reading this is wrong, messages in akka should typically be small.

What is the correct approach in akka?
Should I really sent 10.000 à 100.000 messages of 100 byte each?
Should I sent messages of 100 objects each?

Answer (score 0):

Database persistence is a separate issue and IMHO belongs in a question of its own.

As for the list of items you want to send, you can either batch them into small chunks or send them individually (this is the preferred option).

The Akka.NET blog has a good article with rationale on why messages should not be "fat": https://petabridge.com/blog/large-messages-and-sockets-in-akkadotnet/

Comment: Do you have a reference about the preferred option? I understand the rationale, but also I am looking for experience out of praxis.

Comment: I split the question like you suggested.